# quicksort ~20 times slower than mergesort even with median used as pivot?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I implemented this version of quicksort by taking the median of 3 elements as the pivot:

```
def rearrange_array(array, begin_index, end_index):
    # choose 3 random indexes in the array
    index1 = randint(begin_index, int(begin_index + (end_index - begin_index)/3))
    index2 = randint(int(begin_index + (end_index - begin_index)/3), int(begin_index + 2*(end_index - begin_index)/3))
    index3 = randint(int(begin_index + 2*(end_index - begin_index)/3), end_index)

    if array[index1] > array[index2]:
        tmp = array[index1]
        array[index1] = array[index2]
        array[index2] = tmp
    if array[index2] > array[index3]:
        tmp = array[index2]
        array[index2] = array[index3]
        array[index3] = tmp
    if array[index1] > array[index2]:
        tmp = array[index1]
        array[index1] = array[index2]
        array[index2] = tmp

    # swap index2 and begin_index
    tmp = array[index2]
    array[index2] = array[end_index]
    array[end_index] = tmp

def partition(array, start_index, end_index): # partition = conquer
    rearrange_array(array, start_index, end_index)
    pivot = array[end_index] # pivot is always the right most index
    i = start_index - 1
    # if an element is samller than pivot swap it in front
    for j in range(start_index, end_index):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            # swap
            tmp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[j]
            array[j] = tmp
    # swap the pivot with the element after i
    # since i only goes forward once something smaller than the pivot is found, we know that
    # everything in front of i+1 will be smaller than pivot
    tmp = array[i+1]
    array[i+1] = array[end_index]
    array[end_index] = tmp
    return i + 1

def quicksort_recursive(array, start_index, end_index):
    if start_index < end_index:
        pivot_index = partition(array, start_index, end_index)
        quicksort_recursive(array, start_index, pivot_index - 1)
        quicksort_recursive(array, pivot_index, end_index)
```

to test the sorting algorithm, I used it on an array of 100k elements which took ~16 seconds

```
def get_array(length, maximum):
    array = []
    for _ in range(length):
        array.append(randint(0, maximum))
    return array
sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 100)
a = get_array(100000, 100)
t = time()
quicksort_recursive(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
print(time() - t)
```

Then I compared it to this version of quicksort, which only took about 0.8-1 second:

```
def merge(array, left, right):
    # the program will only get here once we call mergesort on
    # a one element array
    i = j = k = 0
    # put the smallest one in the array
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            array[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            array[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    # if one array still has stuff left:
    while i < len(left):
        array[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(right):
        array[k] = right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def mergesort_recursive(array):
    # 1. devide the array in 2
    if len(array) > 1:
        # divide
        middle_index = int(len(array)/2)
        left = array[:middle_index]
        right = array[middle_index:]
        # conquer
        mergesort_recursive(left)
        mergesort_recursive(right)
        # merge
        merge(array, left, right)
```

I'm a bit confused about this, isn't quicksort supposed to be faster than mergesort? I've tried it on an array of 100 elements and it does put the elements in correct order so I'm not sure what's going on

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a job for [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Both are O(n lg n) in the expected case, which means you *do* need to worry about the constants hidden in the asymptotic complexity. Median-of-3 will help you avoid the worst-case O(n^2) behavior for quicksort, but at the cost of increasing the hidden constant. (Especially because you are adding another function call into the mix, which `mergesort` avoids. What happens if you inline `rearrange_array`?)

Comment: Median-0f-3 is pretty expensive in many cases, especially if you don't have a lower threshold cutoff.  I'd recommend that you use a simpler way to mediate worst-case scenarios like just picking the midpoint as the pivot.  (I think that's what @rcgldr is doing in their answer)

Comment: it does indeed avoid the worst case senario of O(n^2), does this mean it might be a problem with python (ex. function calls being rather expensive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples, didn't used median of 3. On my system, quick sort 0.312 seconds, bottom up merge sort 0.436 seconds, top down merge sort 0.500 seconds. Note for these type of programs, python is over 50 times slower than a compiled language like C or C++.

quick sort hoare partition scheme

```
import random
from time import time

def qsort(a, lo, hi):
    if(lo >= hi):
        return
    p = a[(lo + hi) // 2]       # pivot, any a[] except a[hi]
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi + 1
    while(1):
        while(1):               # while(a[++i] < p)
            i += 1
            if(a[i] >= p):
                break
        while(1):               # while(a[--j] < p)
            j -= 1
            if(a[j] <= p):
                break
        if(i >= j):
            break
        a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
    qsort(a, lo, j)
    qsort(a, j+1, hi)

# test sort
a = [random.randint(0, 2147483647) for r in range(100*1024)]
s = time()
qsort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
e = time()
print e - s

# check to see if data was sorted
f = 0
for i in range (1 ,len(a)):
    if(a[i-1] > a[i]):
        f = 1
        break
if(f == 0):
    print("sorted")
else:
    print("error")
```

bottom up merge sort

```
import random
from time import time

def sort(a):
    if(len(a) < 2):                     # if nothing to do, return
        return
    b = [0] * len(a)                    # allocate b
    mrgsrt(a, b, len(a))

def mrgsrt(a, b, n):
    s = 1                               # assume even pass count
    if((passcnt(n) & 1) == 1):          #  if odd count
        while(s < n):                   #   swap pairs in place
            if(a[s] < a[s-1]):
                a[s-1],a[s] = a[s],a[s-1]
            s = s + 2
        s = 2
    while(s < n):
        ee = 0                          # reset end index
        while(ee < n):                  # setup for next pair of runs
            ll = ee
            rr = ll + s
            if(rr >= n):                #  if only left run copy it
                b[ll:n] = a[ll:n]
                break
            ee = rr + s
            if(ee > n):
                ee = n
            mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee)
        a,b = b,a                       # swap(a, b)
        s = s << 1                      # double run size

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return

def passcnt(n):                         # return # passes
    i = 0
    s = 1
    while(s < n):
        s = s << 1
        i = i + 1
    return(i)

# test sort
a = [random.randint(0, 2147483647) for r in range(100*1024)]
c = a[:]                                # c = sorted copy of a
c.sort()
s = time()
sort(a)
e = time()
print e - s

# check to see if data was sorted properly
f = 0
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    if(a[i] != c[i]):
        f = 1
        break
if(f == 0):
    print("sorted")
else:
    print("error")
```

top down merge sort

```
import random
from time import time

def sort(a):
    if(len(a) < 2):                     # if nothing to do, return
        return
    b = [0] * len(a)                    # allocate b
    msa2a(a, b, 0, len(a))              # merge sort a to a

def msa2a(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to a
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2b(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to b
    msa2b(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to b
    mrg(b, a, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from b to a

def msa2b(a, b, low, end):              # merge sort a to b
    if((end - low) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        b[low] = a[low]                 #   copy 1 element from a to b
        return                          #   return
    mid = (low+end)//2                  # set mid point
    msa2a(a, b, low, mid)               # merge sort left  half to a
    msa2a(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to a
    mrg(a, b, low, mid, end)            # merge halves   from a to b

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return

# test sort
a = [random.randint(0, 2147483647) for r in range(100*1024)]
c = a[:]                                # c = sorted copy of a
c.sort()
s = time()
sort(a)
e = time()
print e - s

# check to see if data was sorted properly
f = 0
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    if(a[i] != c[i]):
        f = 1
        break
if(f == 0):
    print("sorted")
else:
    print("error")
```